# Derivative of nuclear norm of $xx^T-V$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, nuclear-norm

The function is

$$f(x) = \| x x^T - V \|_*$$

where $\| \cdot \|_*$ denotes the nuclear norm and $V$ is a given matrix. $x$ is a vector. Please tell me how to differentiate $f(x)$. And, if it is possible, please show me how to compute the 2nd derivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: Could you define *nuclear norm*? I never heard that term before.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/701062/339790)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new matrix variable $$M=xx^T-V$$Then find the differential of the function in terms of this new variable
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \operatorname{tr}\sqrt{M^TM} \cr
\cr
df &= \frac{1}{2}(M^TM)^{-1/2}:d(M^TM) \cr
   &= \frac{1}{2}(M^TM)^{-1/2}:(dM^TM+M^TdM) \cr
   &= (M^TM)^{-1/2}:M^TdM \cr
   &= M(M^TM)^{-1/2}:dM \cr
   &= M(M^TM)^{-1/2}:d(xx^T) \cr
   &= M(M^TM)^{-1/2}:(dx\,x^T+x\,dx^T) \cr
   &= \big(M(M^TM)^{-1/2} + (M^TM)^{-1/2}M^T\big)\,x:dx \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \big(M(M^TM)^{-1/2} + (M^TM)^{-1/2}M^T\big)\,x \cr\cr
}$$
This is the gradient. To find the hessian you must differentiate again wrt $x$. But it's going to be very messy since each term $M$ contains two $x$'s inside of it.

And we can't use the "trace trick" again
$$\operatorname{tr}(f(X))= f^\prime(X^T):dX$$
since there are no traces left in the gradient.

If there is other information that would simplify the problem (e.g. $V$ is symmetric), then you might be able to find an explicit formula for the hessian.

If you want the hessian in order to use something like Newton's method, I would suggest that you try a gradient-based method instead.

### Update

Since $V\!=\!V^T\,$ the [Matrix Sign](https://github.com/higham/what-is/blob/master/matrix_sign.pdf) function can be used to write the gradient
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
 = 2\,\operatorname{sign}\left(xx^T-V\right)\,x
$$

Comment: great thanks. By the way, what does colon ':' mean?

Comment: It is the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product. In index notation $$A:B = A_{ij}\,B_{ij}$$