# Matrix Differentiation of Fraction Power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, nuclear-norm

I encounter a problem where I wish to calculate:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{X}}\,\operatorname{tr}\left(\left( \boldsymbol{X X}^\top \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)
$$
[Peterson](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf) gave a very thorough discussion on different types of matrix differentiation, including ones involving quadratic trace. Nevertheless, I am at a loss when I have fraction power. I tried as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{X}}\,\operatorname{tr}\left( \boldsymbol{X X} ^\top\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}} &= \left \{ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{X}^{1/2}}\,\operatorname{tr}\left( \boldsymbol{X X} ^\top \right)^{1/2} \right\}^\top\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{X}^{1/2}}{\partial\boldsymbol{X}}
\end{align}
$$
Yet, I found it seems that the chain rule cannot be applied this way as $\boldsymbol{X}^{1/2}$ may not exist if $\boldsymbol{X}$ is not square.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$N = {\rm tr}\Big(\sqrt{XX^T}\Big)$$ is known as the Nuclear norm of $X^T$.

The gradient is given by either
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial N}{\partial X}
  &= (XX^T)^{-1/2}\,X \cr
  &= X\,(X^TX)^{-1/2} \cr
\cr
}$$
If the SVD of $X$ is available, then
$$\eqalign{
 X &= USV^T \cr
\frac{\partial N}{\partial X}
  &= UV^T \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks Greg. Would you also suggest some reference or textbook where I can read more about Nuclear norm and the SVD formulation?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/701062/357854)

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y = X X^\top$. Then $Y$ is symmetric and has real eigenvalues. If it is invertible then the eigenvalues are positive. So there is a unique square root. Applying the chain rule, you just need to differentiate $Y^{1/2}$ with respect to $Y$ and then $X X^\top$ with respect to $X$.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I will try this method to see whether I can get some result.