# Derivative of the nuclear norm ${\left\| {XA} \right\|_*}$ with respect to $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, nuclear-norm

The nuclear norm (also known as trace norm) is defined as

\begin{equation}
{\left\| M \right\|_*} = \mbox{tr} \left( {\sqrt {{M^T}M} } \right) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\min \left\{ {m,n} \right\}} {{\sigma _i}\left( M \right)} 
\end{equation}
where ${\sigma _i}\left( M \right)$ denotes the $i$-th singular value of $M$.

My question is how to compute the derivative of ${\left\| {XA} \right\|_*}$ with respect to $X$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\frac{{\partial {{\left\| {XA} \right\|}_*}}}{{\partial X}}
\end{equation}
In fact, I want to use it for the gradient descent optimization algorithm.

Note that there is [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701062/derivative-of-the-nuclear-norm-with-respect-to-its-argument?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), according to which the sub-gradient of ${\left\| X \right\|_*}$  is $U{V^T}$, where $U\Sigma {V^T}$ is the SVD decomposition of $X$. I hope this is helpful. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Did you read Michael Grant's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/704271/339790)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for your suggestion. I just read Michael Grant's answer right now. Although I haven’t made it clear, actually, I want to use ${\left\| {XA} \right\|_*}$ as a loss function in a deep neural network (DNN). As is known, the optimization algorithm for DNNs can be easily implemented if we can compute the gradient. There is [a recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04038.pdf) which optimizes ${\left\| {X} \right\|_*}$ using its sub-gradient $UV^T$, and I think it maybe appropriate to follow this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$Y=XA$$
Write the norm in terms of this new variable, then find the differential and do a change of variables from $Y\rightarrow X$ to obtain the desired gradient 
$$\eqalign{
\phi&=\|Y\|_* \cr
d\phi
 &= (YY^T)^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}Y:dY \cr
 &= (YY^T)^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}Y:dX\,A \cr
 &= (YY^T)^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}YA^T:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X}
 &= (YY^T)^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}YA^T \cr
 &= Y(Y^TY)^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}A^T \cr\cr
}$$
There are two ways of writing the inverse of the square root, only one of which makes sense when $Y$ is rectangular (full column rank -vs- full row rank).

Comment: Dear greg, thank you so much for your answer. Although I have no ability to verify your answer, it seems to be correct. Besides, I have an additional problem: is it true that $Y{({Y^T}Y)^{ - {\textstyle{1 \over 2}}}}{A^T} = \tilde U{\tilde V^T}A^T$ where $Y = \tilde U\tilde \Sigma {\tilde V^T}$  like [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/701104/561512) of another [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701062/derivative-of-the-nuclear-norm-with-respect-to-its-argument?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)?

Comment: @Jack  Yes, if you know the SVD of $Y$, then the solution can be simplified to $$ \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} = UV^TA^T $$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and it means a lot to me.