# Derivative of matrix nuclear norm

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, nuclear-norm

I'm trying to find the derivative of

$$|(L^TL - \sigma)|_1 = \mbox{Tr} \left( \sqrt{(L^TL - \sigma)^\dagger(L^TL - \sigma)} \right)$$

with respect to $L$, where $\dagger$ is the transpose conjugate and $\sigma$ is some matrix.

I tried doing this with differentials and ended up at 
$$\begin{align}
&\partial\text{Tr}\left(\sqrt{(L^TL - \sigma)^\dagger(L^TL - \sigma)}\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(L^TL - \sigma)^\dagger(L^TL - \sigma)}}\right)^T:\left(dX^\dagger (X - \sigma) + (X - 1)^\dagger dX\right)
\end{align}$$

where $X = L^TL$. This doesn't look too promising as I eventually only want $dL$ terms. Could someone point out how to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: This is sometimes called the Nuclear norm. Here is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701062/).

Comment: I had never seen the nuclear norm referred to as $1$-norm.

Comment: It's the [Schatten p-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Schatten_norms) with $p=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$\eqalign{
M &= L^TL-\Sigma,\quad
 S &= \big(M^TM\big)^{1/2},\quad
 \phi &= \|M\|_* = {\rm Tr}(S)
}$$
Then, assuming all the matrices are real 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial L}
 &= LMS^{-1}+LS^{-1}M^T \cr
}$$

The detailed calculations follow.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= M(M^TM)^{-1/2}:dM \cr
 &= MS^{-1}:(L^TdL + dL^TL) \cr
 &= \big(MS^{-1}+S^{-1}M^T\big):L^TdL \cr
 &= L\big(MS^{-1}+S^{-1}M^T\big):dL \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial L}
 &= L\big(MS^{-1}+S^{-1}M^T\big) \cr
}$$
where a colon represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)\cr}$$

---

**Update**

If all the matrices are complex, and Wirtinger derivatives are acceptable to you, then 
$$\eqalign{
M &= L^\dagger L-\Sigma,\quad
 S = \big(M^\dagger M\big)^{1/2},\quad
 \phi = {\rm Tr}(S) \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial L} &= \tfrac{1}{2}L^*M^*S^{-1} \cr
}$$
If $L$ is real (i.e. $L=L^*,\, L^\dagger=L^T$), and all the others are complex then
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial L}
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}L\big(M^*S^{-1}+(S^*)^{-1}M^\dagger\big) \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case though $S = M^\dagger M$ and the matrices aren't real. But I will try to adapt your technique to the complex case. Thank you!

Comment: It's strange that you've use $L^TL$.  Is $L$ real or complex?

Comment: You're right, I think I should use $L^\dagger L$. Thank you so much for writing such detailed answers! Really appreciate it!