# Gradient of trace norm of complex matrix

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms

**The problem:**

Let $S \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times M}$ with $N > M$ and $S^{H}S=\mathbb{I}$, let $\rho$ and $\sigma$ be hermitian matrices of trace $1$ and define the function $D: \mathbb{C}^{N\times M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as:

$$D(S) = \text{tr}(|S\rho S^{H} - \sigma|),$$

with $|A-B| = (A-B)(A-B)^{H}$ and $^H$ denoting the hermitian transpose, i.e., $D$ is the trace distance. My goal is to compute $\nabla_S D(S)$, the gradient of $D$ w.r.t $S$.

**My approach:**

I defined the following variables:

$$A = S\rho S - \sigma$$
$$B = A^H A.$$

$D$ then becomes:

$$D = tr(B^{1/2})$$

The goal is now to take the differential of $D$ and rearrange terms to eventually arrive at something like:

$$dD = \text{tr} (K dS),$$

with the transpose of $K$, $K^T$, being the gradient we're looking for.

My progress so far:

$$dD = d(\text{tr}(B^{1/2}) = \text{tr}(d(B^{1/2}))$$
$$dD = \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}((B^{-1/2})^T dB)$$

We have:

$$dB = (dA)^HA + A^HdA$$

And:

$$dA = dS\rho S^H + S\rho (dS)^H$$

I will now get terms with $dS$ and terms with $(dS)^H$ and I'm not sure how to manipulate them to get to an expression from which I can read out the gradient. Is this even the (or a) right approach?

Comment: Isn't that the Frobenius norm?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo not quite. In the Frobenius norm the trace is inside the square root. This is the trace norm up to a constant.

Comment: Do you mean the nuclear norm?

Comment: I believe the nuclear norm and the trace norm refer to the same norm, so yes.

Comment: Then you might want to take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/701062/339790).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done all the hard work, now you just need to do some algebra to substitute the  various differentials and rearrange things into a suitable form.
$$\eqalign{
dB &= dA^HA + A^HdA \cr
   &= (dS\,pS^H + Sp\,dS^H)^HA + A^H(dS\,pS^H + Sp\,dS^H) \cr
   &= (Sp^H\,dS^H + dS\,p^HS^H)A + A^H(dS\,pS^H + Sp\,dS^H) \cr
   &= (dS\,p^HS^HA + A^HdS\,pS^H) + (Sp^H\,dS^HA + A^HSp\,dS^H) \cr
   &= (dS-{\rm terms}) \quad+\quad (dS^H-{\rm terms}) \cr
\cr
C &= \tfrac{1}{2}\big(B^{-1/2}\big)^T \quad {\rm \big(for\,convenience\big)} \cr
\cr
dD &= C:dB \cr
  &= C:dS\,p^HS^HA + C:A^HdS\,pS^H + (dS^H-{\rm terms}) \cr
  &= (CA^TS^*p^* + A^*CS^*p^T):dS \quad + ({\rm terms}):dS^H \cr
\frac{\partial D}{\partial S} &= CA^TS^*p^* + A^*CS^*p^T \cr
}$$
The gradient wrt the conjugate variable is simply the conjugate of the gradient. 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial D}{\partial S^H} &= (CA^TS^*p^* + A^*CS^*p^T)^H \cr
}$$
**NB:**   Colons denote trace/Frobenius products, i.e. $\,A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$