# Gradient of the trace distance (Schatten $1$-norm)

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm

Suppose that matrices $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian and positive semidefinite. How can I obtain the gradient of the trace distance between $A$ and $B$, i.e., $$C := \Vert A - B \Vert_1 := \mbox{Tr} \left( \sqrt{(A-B)^\dagger (A-B)}\right)$$ with respect to $A$, i.e., $\nabla_A C$?

Comment: IMHO, you should not have chosen $C$.  A norm is a nonnegative real.  Thus, you should not pick the same notation for scalars and matrices.  I would have picked $c$ instead.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Schatten 1-norm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) is the same as the nuclear norm. It's also called as trace norm. All three norms calculate a sum of singular values of a matrix. Good point, sorry for the confusion on the notation $C$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/704271/339790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\h{{\frac 12}}
\def\n{{-\frac 12}}
X &= (A-B) \quad\implies\quad dX = dA \\
W &= X^{\dagger}X \\
}$$
and use it to calculate the requested gradient
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}
C &= {\rm Tr}\!\LR{W^\h} \\
dC &= \h\LR{W^T}^\n:dW \\
 &= \h\LR{W^\n}^*:{X^{\dagger}dX} \\
 &= \h\LR{XW^\n}^*:dA \\
\frac{\p C}{\p A}
 &= \h\LR{X\LR{X^{\dagger}X}^\n}^* \\
}$$
Since $X$ is Hermitian, this result can be further simplified and conjugated
$$\eqalign{
S &= {\rm sign}(X) \;=\; X\LR{X^2}^\n \\
\frac{\p C}{\p A}
 &= \h\LR{X\LR{X^2}^\n}^* = \frac{S^*}2 \\
\frac{\p C}{\p A^*} &= \frac{S}2 \\
}$$
Here is more information about the [matrix sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_sign_function) function.

Answer (score 1):

Following the post recommended by [Rodrigo](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/704271/339790),
the distance $\phi$ is
the Schatten-1 norm (or nuclear norm) of $\mathbf{X}$
is the sum of its singular values
$$
\phi(\mathbf{X})
= \sum_k s_k(\mathbf{X})
= \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{S})
$$
where we consider the singular value decomposition,
$\mathbf{X}
=\mathbf{A-B}
=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{S}\mathbf{V}^T$,

It holds the following result for the differential
$$
d\mathbf{S}
=
\mathrm{diag}
\left[ \mathbf{U}^T (d\mathbf{X}) \mathbf{V} \right]
$$
thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\phi
&=&
\mathrm{tr}[d\mathbf{S}]
=
\mathrm{tr}
\left[ \mathbf{U}^T (d\mathbf{X}) \mathbf{V} \right] 
=
\mathbf{U}\mathbf{V}^T: d\mathbf{X}
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{A}}
=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{V}^T$$ is the requested gradient (in the real case).
I think this can be generalized to the complex case.

Comment: +1 Generalizing to the complex case (in the Wirtinger sense) yields
$$
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\def\u{\left(UV^H\right)}
\g CA = \frac{\u^*}2 \qquad\quad
\g C{A^*} = \frac\u2
$$